# Calculate 3D Parallelepiped corners , when given min,max bounds .

Tags: geometry

I need to find out other 2 3D corners points of rotated,translated Parallelepiped .

I have the min,max 3D points of The Parallelepiped bounds (left top corner,right bottom corner) , How do I calculate the 2 other corner points please ?

The information I have : 

1. Width/Height 

2. Start 4 corners before rotate and translate

3. Rotation axis 

4. Rotation angel

Example (y pointing down and z pointing to viewer(us) x to right ):

Parallelepiped before rotation,translation :

A(-5,5,0)  B(5,5,0)  C(-5,5,0) D(5,5,0)

Rotate around X axis (1,0,0) with -90 Degree
Translate up on y axis -5

Information I have after rotation,translocation :

Min(-5,-5,-5)   Max(5,-5,5)

Need to know the 2 other points for any rotation , translation please.

Thanks !

Edit(1 AM):

So basically while waiting for answer I understood that i should take each point and apply to it rotation+translation with this matrix :

[Rotation matrix from axis and angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MbhJ.png)

Edit(4 AM):

This method works but I miss something in next example please let me know whats wrong :

The Parallelepiped local points in world (start position) :
A(0,0,0) B(10,0,0) C(0,-10,0) D(10,-10,0)

Translation  X -5 , Y -10 and rotation -90 Degree around X axis u=(1,0,0) .

Result after multiply each matrix(row)* col(point) and adding translocation to each point :

A(-5,-10,0)  B(5,-10,0) C(-5,-10,10) D(5,-10,10)

This is wrong because the result should be at height -5 and z between 5,-5,
Its seems like the rotation goes around wrong origin , 
I have also been trying replace actions rotate then translate...
can you please help me understand ?

Edit (6 AM):

I need some how to edit this matrix(Rotation matrix from axis and angle) so it will rotate the Parallelepiped around its self and not around the 0,0,0 of world ,please help !

Last Edit... I found solution, I translate the pivot center of the Parallelepiped  to be at origin of the world and then make translations and the restoring of points with the rotation matrix works . 
Any way would be nice to know how to use this matrix to rotate around given pivot additionally to rotating direction vector.

Comment: Replace "rectangle" by "parallelepiped".

Comment: Done , thanks sir !